# Get the selected cells count in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

How to get the selected cells count and selected cells array from UICollectionView, I need to set the limit of selection. Below is my code which is not working. Please guide. Thanks

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
        print(indexPaths)
    if let selectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
                if selectedItems.count >= 3 {
                    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
                    return false
                }
            }
    return true
}
```

Above code when written in didSelect method returns only selected cell index but here just skip to last line

```
return true
```

Comment: You can get selected items indexpath but you can't get array of selected cells, because cells are for reuse

Comment: @SPatel I need to get the selected cells count at least

Comment: on didSelect just store it's index path in array (if allready contain then remove it)

Comment: @SPateli don't think so. we can get count from collection.indexPathsForSelectedItems

Comment: Have you  set `allowsMultipleSelection` to true?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes

Comment: As being said we can get the number of selected cells from the `indexPathsForSelectedItems.count`, and the check should be made before actually selecting the cell in the `shouldSelectItemAt`.  See my working example below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shouldSelectItemAt` delegate method from the `UICollectionViewDelegate` to achieve that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0 <=  selectionLimit
}
```

A sample demo to demonstrate how it works:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    private var myCollectionView:UICollectionView?
    private var selectionLimit = 4

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.7, height: 60)

        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        myCollectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        myCollectionView?.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView?.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(myCollectionView ?? UICollectionView())

        self.view = view
    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return myCell
    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Did select a cell at \(indexPath.row)")
        let itemsLeftToSelect = selectionLimit - (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0)
        print("Have \(itemsLeftToSelect) items to select")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Did deselect a cell at \(indexPath.row)")
        let itemsLeftToSelect = selectionLimit - (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0)
        print("Have \(itemsLeftToSelect) items to select")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0 <  selectionLimit
    }
}
```

When you reach the selection limit, `shouldSelectItemAt` will return false and `didSelectItemAt` function will not be called anymore. On the other hand if you click on the already selected cell, `didDeselectItemAt` will be called and you will be called, and you are able to select + 1 cell again, as the number of selected items will decrease with 1. See also the debug logs in the example.

Comment: not working, just printing the selected cell's index

Comment: @iPhone7 Most probably your  `indexPathsForSelectedItems` array returns 1 because you have  `allowsMultipleSelection` set to false. Try to set it to true, and it will work

Comment: if so, I should not be allowed to select multiple cells but I can

Comment: @iPhone7 see my update. I included an example for you to be able to test it.

Comment: Sorry to say but not working too, didDeselect is never called. Even when deselecting a cell

Comment: didSelectItemAt is called in both cases either select or deselect cell

Comment: @iPhone7 double check it. The console log text is quite similar, maybe there the confusion. Either `didSelectItemAt` or `didDeselectItemAt` called, depending if the cell is already selected or not. If the cell is selected than you click on it `didDeselectItemAt` will be called. If the cell is not selected and you click on it `didSelectItemAt` will be called.

Comment: I know that bro

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is **model** based.

In your data model add a property

```
var isSelected = false
```

and re-/set it accordingly when a cell is de-/selected.

Then you can simply count the selected data source items  – `dataSource` represents the data source array

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return dataSource.filter{$0.isSelected}.count < 3
}
```

Further there is no need to deselect a row in this method as you are preventing the user from selecting more than 2 rows.